# PyQt progress jumps to 100% after it starts

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt, pyqt5, qprogressbar

When I run the code in the in the `doWork` method, by clicking the `button1`, the progress bar works as expected.

However, when I pass the list to the `doWork` method from other methods (i.e. `btn2`, `btn3`), the progress bar just jumps to 100% after it starts.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def doWork(self, lst=['http://www.somesite.com/',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page2',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page3']):
        progress = 0
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        links = lst
        for link in links:
            browser.get(link)
            progress += 100 / len(links)
            self.progressChanged.emit(progress)
        browser.close()

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start1")
        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start2")
        button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start3")
        lay.addWidget(progressBar)
        lay.addWidget(button1)
        lay.addWidget(button2)
        lay.addWidget(button3)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = SeleniumWorker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.doWork)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.btn2)
        button3.clicked.connect(self.btn3)
        self.worker.progressChanged.connect(progressBar.setValue)


    def btn2(self):
        self.lst2 = ['http://www.somesite.com/page4',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page5',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page6']
        self.worker.doWork(self.lst2)

    def btn3(self):
        self.lst3 = ['http://www.somesite.com/page7',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page8',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page9']
        self.worker.doWork(self.lst3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In what order do you click the buttons? Does a different order give different result (i.e. not clicking button1 first)? Have you tried delays and debug prints of `progress` from your worker thread?

Comment: @handle The order doesn't make any difference, except that when I click on `button1` the second time it won't execute. But, I can click on  `button2` and `button3` any number of times, in any order, I will always get the same results.

Comment: I just installed pyqt5 and selenium plus geckodriver; progress bar stays at 100 percent. Might have to do with moving the object to the thread. I'll play with it a bit...

Comment: To run the code in the thread you need to do so via `QThread.start()`

Comment: @JoeT.Boka In my answer I have placed an explanation of the operation of the QThread with a worker, check it. :D

Comment: As the answer probably already states, it's not running as thread via the additional buttons and thus blocking the Qt event loop, causing the progress bar to jump straight to 100 only after the work is done (so the order actually does make a difference!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have not understood the logic of my [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631464/pyqt-qprogressbar-not-working-when-i-use-it-with-selenuim), I will detail the procedure:

```
[1] self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
[2] self.worker = SeleniumWorker()
[3] self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
[4] self.worker.progressChanged.connect(progressBar.setValue, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
[5] self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.doWork)
```

1. `QThread` is a thread handler, so an object of that class allows us to execute a task on a thread other than the main thread called the GUI thread.
2. You are creating a SeleniumWorker object that has the doWork method, which is a blocking task that should not be executed in the GUI thread, and that will be achieved with the previous QThread.
3. Since the function must be executed in another thread, the object that has that method must move to that other thread.
4. The signal of the object that is in the other thread is connected to the `QProgressBar` that is in the GUI thread, this connection must be made with the flag `QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection`.
5. When the thread is started it will call the doWork function and since the self.worker object is in another thread then the function will also be executed in that other thread.

---

In your case in the code that is shown in the next part you are calling the `doWork` function when the thread has not yet started so it will be executed in the main thread.

```
def btn2(self):
    ...
    # main thread
    self.worker.doWork(self.lst2)
```

---

One way to pass the urls is through a setter method, and then start the thread. When the thread starts, it will call `doWork`, and when the `doWork` is executed, the `progressChanged` signal will be emited.

With all the above we obtain the following:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def setUrls(self, urls=['http://www.somesite.com/',
    'http://www.somesite.com/page2',
    'http://www.somesite.com/page3']):
        self.urls = urls

    def doWork(self):
        self.started.emit()
        progress = 0
        self.progressChanged.emit(progress)
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        links = self.urls
        for link in links:
            browser.get(link)
            progress += 100 / len(links)
            self.progressChanged.emit(progress)
        browser.close()
        self.finished.emit()

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start1")
        button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start2")
        button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start3")
        lay.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        lay.addWidget(button1)
        lay.addWidget(button2)
        lay.addWidget(button3)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = SeleniumWorker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.progressChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.doWork)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.btn1)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.btn2)
        button3.clicked.connect(self.btn3)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.worker.started.connect(lambda: self.buttons_setEnable(False))

    def on_finished(self):
        self.buttons_setEnable(True)
        if self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.quit()
            self.thread.wait()

    def buttons_setEnable(self, enable):
        for btn in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
            btn.setEnabled(enable)

    def btn1(self):
        self.worker.setUrls()
        self.thread.start()

    def btn2(self):
        lst2 = ['http://www.somesite.com/page4',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page5',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page6']
        self.worker.setUrls(lst2)
        self.thread.start()

    def btn3(self):
        lst3 = ['http://www.somesite.com/page7',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page8',
        'http://www.somesite.com/page9']
        self.worker.setUrls(lst3)
        self.thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***Note***: I have added the functionality of disabling the buttons while it is running as it is appropriate that the thread does not start again while it is working.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I definitely didn't fully understand the logic in your previous solution. I just ran the code you provided here. When I click on any of the buttons, it works for the first time. But, when I click any buttons the second time, nothing is executed.

Comment: You mean you will update your code with the new implementation you mentioned? Because, your current code still has the same issue. I think it's not updated yet.

Comment: I tested you last update 17 minutes ago. The program is crashing when I click any of the buttons. Is it working on your end?

Comment: @JoeT.Boka 
Yes, I realized the problem, I just corrected it and it's tested, sorry for the inconveniences, I've been a little distracted.

Comment: @JoeT.Boka This observing that there is another inconvenience, I am fixing it, when I finish it I notice

Comment: @JoeT.Boka 
Now if you are 100% tested, please try it. :D

Comment: YES! This one is working! Thanks so much for doing this. This is really a complex problem. Awesome solution.